# How to check the assumptions attached to a given symbol?

Tags: assumptions

Suppose there are a number of assumptions attached to a certain symbol.
How do we query Mathematica to see if a given assumption holds?
To be more precise, how can we define a function `elementQ` such that

```
Block[{$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals]}, elementQ[x, Reals]]
(* True *)

Assuming[Element[x, Reals], elementQ[x, Reals]]
(* True *)

elementQ[x, Reals]
(* False *)
```

In some circumstances this is automatically given by `Element` itself: for example `Element[Pi, Reals]` correctly returns `True`. However, the same technique does not work when querying for user-defined assumptions on symbols:

```
Assuming[Element[z, Reals], Element[z, Reals]]
(* Element[z, Reals] *)
```

The matter is of course also complicated by the fact that there are several ways to set assumptions.
Such functions should both check the content of `$Assumptions` and if there are assumptions set up by the use of some `Assuming` or similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `Refine` does what you want

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, Refine[Element[x, Reals]]]
(* True *)

Assuming[x > 0, Refine[Element[x, Reals]]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: well this is kind of embarrassing, I was sure I checked whether `Refine` did the job, and somehow convinced myself it didn't. Anyway, I guess we can say that the function `elementQ[x_, dom_] := Refine[Element[x, dom]] === True` is the solution. Or more generally, `checkAssumption[assumption_] := Refine[assumption] === True`. Thanks for the answer!